# A simple mmap(2) wrapper

Tags: rust, linux, mmap

I've written a wrapper for the `mmap` syscall. It's quite limited in functionality at the moment (there are lots of flags to support) but it's sufficient for mapping anonymous memory regions, which is what I need it for.

It already satisfies `clippy`, so I'm keen to understand some more advanced improvements that use Rust best-practices.

It's split into three files:

1. `lib.rs` containing an `Error` enum
2. `mmap.rs` containing an `Mmap` and `MmapBuilder`
3. `syscall.rs` containing wrapper for the `mmap(2)` syscall

#### `lib.rs`

```
#![allow(clippy::double_must_use)]

pub mod mmap;
pub mod syscall;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub enum Error {
    System(i32),
    NullPointer(&'static str),
}

impl std::error::Error for Error {}

impl std::fmt::Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::System(errno) => std::io::Error::from_raw_os_error(*errno).fmt(f),
            Self::NullPointer(msg) => write!(f, "null pointer: {msg}"),
        }
    }
}
```

#### `mmap.rs`

```
use crate::Error;
use std::ops::{BitOr, Deref, DerefMut};
use std::ptr::NonNull;

/// Represents a memory region that has been mapped with `mmap(2)`.
///
/// This can only be constructed through the use of [`MmapBuilder`].
///
/// Note that using this memory is inherently unsafe because it can concurrently
/// read and written by other processes; the borrow checker has no power here.
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Mmap {
    addr: NonNull<u8>,
    len: usize,
}

impl Mmap {
    #[must_use]
    pub fn builder() -> MmapBuilder {
        MmapBuilder::new()
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn anon(len: usize) -> Result<Mmap, Error> {
        Self::builder().len(len).build()
    }
}

impl Drop for Mmap {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        crate::syscall::munmap(self.addr, self.len).expect("failed to unmap");
    }
}

impl AsRef<[u8]> for Mmap {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(self.addr.as_ptr(), self.len) }
    }
}

impl AsMut<[u8]> for Mmap {
    fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(self.addr.as_ptr(), self.len) }
    }
}

impl Deref for Mmap {
    type Target = [u8];

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self.as_ref()
    }
}

impl DerefMut for Mmap {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        self.as_mut()
    }
}

/// A builder for mmapped memory regions.
#[derive(Default, Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub struct MmapBuilder {
    len: usize,
    prot: i32,
    flags: i32,
    fd: i32,
    offset: i64,
    visibility: Visibility,
    addr: Option<NonNull<u8>>,
}

impl MmapBuilder {
    #[must_use]
    pub fn new() -> MmapBuilder {
        MmapBuilder::default()
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn len(mut self, len: usize) -> Self {
        self.len = len;
        self
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn addr(mut self, addr: Option<NonNull<u8>>) -> Self {
        self.addr = addr;
        self
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn visibility(mut self, visibility: Visibility) -> Self {
        self.visibility = visibility;
        self
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn protection<I: Into<i32>>(mut self, protection: I) -> Self {
        self.prot = protection.into();
        self
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn behavior<I: Into<i32>>(mut self, behavior: I) -> Self {
        self.flags = behavior.into();
        self
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn fd(mut self, fd: i32) -> Self {
        self.fd = fd;
        self
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn offset(mut self, offset: i64) -> Self {
        self.offset = offset;
        self
    }

    #[must_use]
    pub fn build(self) -> Result<Mmap, Error> {
        let addr = crate::syscall::mmap(
            self.addr,
            self.len,
            self.prot,
            self.flags | self.visibility,
            self.fd,
            self.offset,
        )?;
        Ok(Mmap {
            addr,
            len: self.len,
        })
    }
}

#[derive(Default, Hash, Debug, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum Visibility {
    #[default]
    Private,
    Shared,
}

impl From<Visibility> for i32 {
    fn from(value: Visibility) -> Self {
        match value {
            Visibility::Private => libc::MAP_PRIVATE,
            Visibility::Shared => libc::MAP_SHARED,
        }
    }
}

impl BitOr<Visibility> for Visibility {
    type Output = i32;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        i32::from(self) | i32::from(rhs)
    }
}

impl BitOr<Visibility> for i32 {
    type Output = i32;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Visibility) -> Self::Output {
        self | i32::from(rhs)
    }
}

#[derive(Default, Hash, Debug, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum Behavior {
    #[default]
    Anonymous,
}

impl From<Behavior> for i32 {
    fn from(value: Behavior) -> Self {
        match value {
            Behavior::Anonymous => libc::MAP_ANONYMOUS,
        }
    }
}

impl BitOr<Behavior> for Behavior {
    type Output = i32;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        i32::from(self) | i32::from(rhs)
    }
}

impl BitOr<Behavior> for i32 {
    type Output = i32;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Behavior) -> Self::Output {
        self | i32::from(rhs)
    }
}

/// Memory protection flags for mmap.
#[derive(Default, Hash, Debug, Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum Protection {
    Exec,
    Read,
    Write,
    #[default]
    None,
}

impl From<Protection> for i32 {
    fn from(value: Protection) -> Self {
        match value {
            Protection::Exec => libc::PROT_EXEC,
            Protection::Read => libc::PROT_READ,
            Protection::Write => libc::PROT_WRITE,
            Protection::None => libc::PROT_NONE,
        }
    }
}

impl BitOr<Protection> for Protection {
    type Output = i32;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        i32::from(self) | i32::from(rhs)
    }
}

impl BitOr<Protection> for i32 {
    type Output = i32;

    fn bitor(self, rhs: Protection) -> Self::Output {
        self | i32::from(rhs)
    }
}
```

#### `syscall.rs`

```
use crate::Error;
use std::ptr::NonNull;

pub(crate) fn mmap(
    addr: Option<NonNull<u8>>,
    len: usize,
    prot: i32,
    flags: i32,
    fd: i32,
    offset: i64,
) -> Result<NonNull<u8>, Error> {
    let ret = unsafe {
        let ptr = addr.map(NonNull::as_ptr).unwrap_or(std::ptr::null_mut());
        libc::mmap(ptr as *mut _, len, prot, flags, fd, offset)
    };

    if ret == libc::MAP_FAILED {
        Err(Error::System(errno()))
    } else {
        NonNull::new(ret as *mut _).ok_or(Error::NullPointer("mmap returned null"))
    }
}

pub(crate) fn munmap(addr: NonNull<u8>, len: usize) -> Result<(), Error> {
    let ret = unsafe { libc::munmap(addr.as_ptr() as *mut _, len) };

    if ret == -1 {
        Err(Error::System(errno()))
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[must_use]
pub(crate) fn errno() -> i32 {
    std::io::Error::last_os_error()
        .raw_os_error()
        .unwrap_or_default()
}
```

Comment: Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Comment: Definitely do add some testcases, and also whenever you have `unsafe` code, do run those testcases under [`cargo miri`](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks pretty good overall.

All I am really missing is tests. Some methods and functions may be covered by unit tests.

Some further, rather opinionated, nitpicks:

- I don't like the `ret` variables in `mmap` and `munmap`. It's a bad name and they're only ever used once.
- I also don't like the uncommented comparison to `-1` in `munmap`. It's a magic number and may warrant a constant or a comment like `// libc::munmap() failed`. A good counter example of what I'd expect is your `ret == libc::MAP_FAILED` which is self-documenting.
- `Protection::None` looks like you could remove it from the enum and use `Option<Protection>` on first glance. However, this would make implementing the `BitOr` stuff a nightmare, though I don't see it being used anywhere anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! How would you test this sort of wrapper? Since mmap only does side effects, and those are a bit hard to check for (you could list /proc/self/maps but that could get complicated when tests are run concurrently) it seems difficult to do well

Comment: Answering my own follow-up comment: msync can be used to check if an address points to a mapped page.

Comment: @haz One possible way to test it is to exercise some use cases - `mmap` some memory, write to it, read the data back and check it's what you expect. If the test survives to that point it's probably a good indicator that things are working :)